# toric variety associated to schur polynomial?

Tags: toric-geometry

In a Schur polynomial, which is homogeneous, monomials are added with fixed coefficients. Collecting the indices of monomials seems to define a toric data for a projective variety. But the coefficients of monomials are not taken into account in this. Is there a way to define a toric variety from schur polynomials which incorporates the coefficients?

Comment: Aren't you really asking if there is a way to attach a toric variety to a polynomial (as opposed to just the exponents in its monomials)? The fact that you are looking at Schur polynomials seems quite irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, only the coefficients of the polynomials are fixed in this case. Is there a way?